# Test Client SOAPFaultException

Tags: web-services

Hi I'm getting below exception when I'm hitting my service using test client .
Can any one help where I went wrong if need any inputs required please tell

```
javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: unknown

at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.fault.SOAP11Fault.getProtocolException(SOAP11Fault.java:178)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.fault.SOAPFaultBuilder.createException(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:111)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:108)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:78)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:107)
    at $Proxy28.publishTravelItinerary(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: It is unlikely to help you without any details. For example, how request looks etc.

Answer (score 1):

you are choosing wrong end point url to invoke webservice from your client.
If you will open ur wsdl,There would be more than one end point url in your wsdl. choose as you configure at your server.

Thanks,
ambuj
"Master yourself, Master the enemy"